# mpmovieplayercontroller sometimes has slow load time, what can be the reason? (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, time, load, performance, mpmoviewcontroller

mpmovieplayercontroller sometimes has slow load time, what can be the reason?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

network connectivity and file size play a big role